# search a dict keys in python

Tags: python

How do I search a dictionary of bigrams for a key if it exists or not and print it's value if does?

```
wordsCounts = {('the','computer'): 2 , ('computer','science'): 3 , ('math','lecture'): 4, ('lecture','day'): 2}
```

So, I want to search if the pair `('math','lecture')` exists or not?

```
pair = ['computer','science']
for k in wordscount.keys():
    if wordscount[k] == pair:
         print wordscount[v]
```

So the result will be a list `('computer','science'): 3`

Answer (score 5):

Just test if the *tuple* of the pair exists:

```
if tuple(pair) in wordscount:
    print wordscount[tuple(pair)]
```

There is no need to loop through all the keys in the dictionary; a python dictionary is much more efficient at finding matching keys if you just give it the key to look for, but it has to be the same type. Your dictionary keys are tuples, so look use a tuple key when searching.

In fact, in python dictionaries, lists are not allowed as keys because they are mutable; you would not be able to search for keys accurately if the keys themselves can be changed.

Comment: Why not just create a tuple in the first place? `pair = ('computer','science')`

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen: I am assuming the user had a list from elsewhere here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The Pythonic way is to try to access the needed element, and catch the exception thrown if it didn't exist.

Comment: @rburny: I was following the OP pattern here. The pythonic way *may* be to ask forgiveness rather than permission, but that [depends on your data patterns](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/175655/python-forgiveness-vs-permission-and-duck-typing/175663#175663) really.

Answer (score 0):

First you may want to know why it does not work..

```
for k in wordscount.keys():
    if wordscount[k] == pair:
```

`wordscount.keys()` will return you list of tuple and next line is to compare value of dict wordsCount to a list 'pair. 
Solution is

```
for k in wordscount.keys():
    if k == tuple(pair):
        print workscount[k]
```

Comment: Thanks bgporter ! I was just about to do that :)